# How to enable button activation with multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make the button active when the checkbox is active. I did this for one checkbox, but how can I do it with 2 checkboxes? Button should not be enabled if even one of the checkboxes is not checked

This is how the button activity I do with a single checkbox:

```
import {useState} from "React";

 export default function App() {

  const [change, setChange] = useState(true);
const buttonHandler = () => {
  setChange(!change)
}

  return (
    <>
      <button disabled={change}>button</button>

      <input type="checkbox" onChange={buttonHandler}/>
      <input type="checkbox" onChange={buttonHandler}/>
      
    <>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to hold the state of both checkboxes to make sure they are both checked before enabling the button:

```
import {useState} from "React";

 export default function App() {

  const [checkbox1, setCheckbox1] = useState(false);
  const [checkbox2, setCheckbox2] = useState(false);
  const button1Handler = () => {
    setCheckbox1(current => !current);
  }
  const button2Handler = () => {
    setCheckbox2(current => !current);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button disabled={!checkbox1 || !checkbox2}>button</button>

      <input type="checkbox" checked={checkbox1} onChange={button1Handler}/>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={checkbox2} onChange={button2Handler}/>
      
    <>
  );
}
```

Comment: I want the button to be active when all checkboxes are checked. When I mark someone, the button becomes active in this code

Comment: Did you try using the edited version where I have negated the condition inside the button `disabled` field?

Comment: Yes i tried but it didn't work

Comment: I've updated the negation condition, so that the button is disabled if either of the checkboxes are unchecked now

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a state that holds an array of values, each of a checkbox. I would prefer an array so you only have one button handler, and adding more checkboxes should be easy.

```
import {useState} from "React";

 export default function App() {

  const [change, setChange] = useState([true, true]);
const buttonHandler = (index) => {
  const newState = [...change];
  newState[index] = !newState[index]
  setChange(newState)
}

  return (
    <>
      <button disabled={!change[0] && !change[1]}>button</button>

      <input type="checkbox" value={change[0]} onChange={()=>buttonHandler(0)}/>
      <input type="checkbox" value={change[1]} onChange={()=>buttonHandler(1)}/>
      
    <>
  );
}
```

Comment: The button for that will always be disabled since an array is always truthy

Comment: Good point. Fixed.

Comment: I want the button to be active when all checkboxes are checked. When I mark someone, the button becomes active in this code